# Calculating max and min numbers in generated random numbers in Java

Tags: java, random

So I have a Java program that generates 100 random integers between 0 and 9 and I need to calculate the max, min and average numbers of generated integers. So far I have

```
import java.util.Random;

public class World {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        public void generateNumber() {

            System.out.println("Generating 100 random integers between 0 and 9");

            Random aGenerator = new Random();

            int randomArray[]=new int[101];
            int countArray[]=new int[10];

            //generate the numbers and store into an array
            int j;
            for (int i=1; i<101; ++i) {
                j=i;
                randomArray[i]=aGenerator.nextInt(10);

                //displaying numbers
                System.out.println("Number " + j + " = " + randomArray[i]);
            }

            int max = randomArray[0];
            for (int i=1; i<randomArray.length; i++) {

                if (randomArray[i] > max) {
                    max =  randomArray[i];
                }
                System.out.println("Max number is "+ max);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints out:

```
Generating 100 random integers between 0 and 9
Number 1 = 2
Number 2 = 9
Number 3 = 3
...
Number 99 = 4
Number 100 = 8
```

which is what I want but the max number part is weird. It prints out that line so many times, how do I make it so that it only prints out once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's printing out the same number of times the `for` loop iterates because the statement is in the loop.

What you want is:

```
 int max = randomArray[0];
 for(int i=1; i<randomArray.length; i++) {
      if(randomArray[i] > max){
         max = randomArray[i];
       }
    }
  System.out.println("Max number is "+ max);
```

Comment: Oh I see my mistake now... Thank you so much for helping!! By the way I'm wondering, if there's something I wanna ask more about this java program, but it's not related to the title of this question, do I post another question or can I ask about it here?

Comment: For that, please post a new question. Also, if this answered your question, please be sure to press the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I tried pressing that button but it said to wait for a few minutes. I'll do that once it lets me

Comment: You should further vote up answers you've accepted.

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputations and I don't have that many yet, I'll definitely do when I have enough though. Thank you for telling me